# Using the YouTube API within a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api, android-viewpager

I using the new YouTube API in my project. Using the example of the documentation, it works correctly:

```
public class Test extends  YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    String urlVideo;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        urlVideo="5lbVNYAeFiQ";

        YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize("MY_API_KEY", this);

    }

    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0,YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
    }

    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer arg1,boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            arg1.loadVideo(urlVideo);
        }

    }
}
```

But in my project, I'm using a main activity that contains a ViewPager
The ViewPager shows fragments, the problem is when I want to show YouTubePlayer within one fragment of ViewPager.
Normally, an activity that uses youtube, extending YouTubeBaseActivity.

```
extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements ... {
```

My question is, how I can show YouTube Player in an activity that extends from fragments?

I searched, but can not find information about my problem.

I sincerely appreciate the help.

Best regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [YouTubePlayerSupportFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) if you are only playing a YouTube video in a single support.v4.app.Fragment. This allows you to use FragmentActivity, rather than YouTubeBaseActivity.

Comment: The problem is the activity extends of Fragment, not of FragmentActivity.
The reason is that it is inside a ViewPager

Comment: If you use YouTubePlayerSupportFragment then your activity does not need to extend anything specific to YouTube.

Comment: please give me sample example for using  YouTubePlayerSupportFragment without extend YoutubeBaseActivity.

Comment: @user2218667 - please read the documentation as it goes through all of the steps required: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment

Comment: yes its playing well on one mode.i have to change the another mode means the app is force closed and getting following error on console window:E/AndroidRuntime(4122): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment did not create a view.How can i clear these error ??? pls give me some suggestions ???