# How to call fragment from activity without using fragmentactivity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-youtube-api

In my project i am using fragments and activities. in one of activity i used youtube video api, now i want to call fragment from that activity but they are not allowing without fragmentactivity and i extended youtubebaseactivity in that activity.so please help me

Comment: please describe with little more detials

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484126/using-the-youtube-api-within-a-fragment

Comment: FragmentTransaction?

Comment: Looks like this is perfect answer for my post https://stackoverflow.com/a/37653673/3962677

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extend `yourclass` with `ActionBarActivity` and you can Access both functionality.

Thats it...

Comment: i m having 5 json array inside json object plz help me

Comment: i didnt get you will you please explain in detail?

Comment: there are 5 different json arrays in the single json object. now i want to parse them and want to store those data

Comment: i cant give response but i can give you structure{
"code":200,
"error":null,
"data":{
"fixtures":[
{
"kickoff":"15:00:00",
"matchdate":"2012-07-28",
"homescore":null,
"awayscore":null,
"attendance":null,
"homepens":null,
"awaypens":null,
"division_id":"5059",
"division":"Testing 1",
"comp":"LGE",
"location":null,
"fixture_note":null,
"hometeam_id":"64930",
"hometeam":"Team 1",
"awayteam_id":"64931",
"awayteam":"Team 2"
}"kickoff":"15:00:00",
"matchdate":"2012-07-28",
"homescore":null,
"awayscore":null,
"attendance":null,
"homepens":null,
"awaypens":null,
}
        ]
    }
}

Comment: in above example there are 2 array in the object like that i am having 5 arrays in single object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66377/discussion-between-jay-and-kamlesh).