# Android How to call Fragment from my Main Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i am very new to android development.

in my case i have one main activity and one fragment created.Main activity as two buttons.

when i click on button, my fragment should load .how can i achieve that?

Mainactivity .XML

```
<Button
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fragment 2"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_button_2"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fragment 1"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_button_1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/fragment_button_2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fragment_button_2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fragment_button_2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="33dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Main activity .java

```
package com.bentgeorge.fragment;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements    View.OnClickListener{
private Button fragment_btn_1;
private Button fragment_btn_2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fragment_btn_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fragment_button_1);
    fragment_btn_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fragment_button_2);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

Fragment1 frag = new Fragment1();
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.mainlayout,frag,"Test Fragment");
transaction.commit();

}
}
```

fragment_fragment1.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.bentgeorge.fragment.Fragment1">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment1.java

```
package com.bentgeorge.fragment;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
* A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
*/
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {


public Fragment1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container,  false);
}

}
```

Not done much codes as i am confused with internet available tutorials.

Please help me to fix this

Thanks & Regards,

Update:

i have done some changes and my fragment is getting loaded now. ut the buttons are still visible . How can i hide the buttons

[image: Fragment]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Updated:**
Please change your MainActivity as like this:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Fragment fragment = new MainFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        }
    }
```

Change your activity_main.xml as like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                
android:id="@+id/fragment_frame"            
android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Please create an xml fragment_main.xml:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 2"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_button_2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 1"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_button_1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/fragment_button_2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fragment_button_2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fragment_button_2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Also create a fragment as MainFragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
     private Button fragment_btn_1;
        private Button fragment_btn_2;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        fragment_btn_1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_button_1);
            fragment_btn_2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_button_2);
            fragment_btn_1.setOnClickListener(this);
            fragment_btn_2.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.fragment_button_1:
                    Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment1();
                    moveToFragment(fragment1);
                    break;
                case R.id.fragment_button_2:
                    Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment2();
                    moveToFragment(fragment2);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void moveToFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        }
}
```

Hope this will helps you. If you had any queries, let me know.

Comment: programe is closing and on IDe i got error like "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0053 (com.bentgeorge.fragment:id/fragment_layout) for fragment Fragment1{148dff74 #0 id=0x7f0c0053}"

Comment: i have created new layout and layout xml is here https://paste.fedoraproject.org/375300/05995146/

Comment: Instead of creating a new xml, please try to give that id for the main layout of activity.

Comment: MainActivity.java : https://paste.fedoraproject.org/375310/65208598/

activity_main.xml : https://paste.fedoraproject.org/375312/14652086/

Fragment1.java : https://paste.fedoraproject.org/375313/52086701/

fragment_fragment1.xml : https://paste.fedoraproject.org/375315/65208704/

fragment.xml : https://paste.fedoraproject.org/375316/14652087/



This is my current code and i am too confused with all those changes.please cosider me as a beginner level

Comment: please write the moveToFragment() as like I had given you. You don't need that fragment.xml. Instead please do as like my edited answer. That is, Please give the id of your RelativeLayout in activity_main.xml as fragment_frame.

Comment: OR in moveToFragment(), change R.id.fragment_frame to R.id.mainlayout. Do any one of these.

Comment: i have done all the changes as same llike u. but here is the result.Fragment is getting lading but button is not hiding.http://s33.postimg.org/9t7pp455b/Screenshot_2016_06_06_16_49_54.png

Comment: please give some background color for fragment. Else you need to make the buttons showing screen as a seperate fragment

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager not exists

Answer (score 3):

in you onClick() method -

```
if(v.getId()==R.id.fragment_button_1){
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.fragment_frame, new Fragment1(), "createPost").addToBackStack(null).commit();
              }
```

where R.id.fragment_frame - rootContainer Id rootView in MainActivity.java

you should use Framelayout for placing fragment in activity.

like below - 
activity_layout.xml -

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myapplication.Activities.TestActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/button1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Button 1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

and your activity - MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_test, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                    replace(R.id.root_layout, new Fragment1()).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

btw your fragment looks good. hope it will help you.

Comment: HI thanks for your reply. Actually i have did some changes in click event and fragment is getting displayed now. but the issue is buttons are still visible on my main screen. how can i hide buttons while loading fragment

Comment: while giving your code, i am getting cannot resolve for "getActivity()" and "addToBackStack"

Comment: set some background in fragment's rootView because probably you are adding fragment on top of activity. or you can also use - replace.(R.id.fragment_frame, new Fragment1()).

Comment: i have tried with "transaction.replace(R.id.mainlayout,frag,"Test Fragment");" also. Same display. i added background color #fff for activity and no difference but one margin white area came inside my main activity

Comment: add background in fragment 's rootView -
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="white_color"
tools:context="com.bentgeorge.fragment.Fragment1">

Comment: i i have given #FFFFFF ad background, only thing is fragment is showing in white box but buttons are still there

Comment: please add your activity.xml. are you adding fragment in your root container of activity?

Comment: activity_main.xml : https://paste.fedoraproject.org/375304/20722814/ . i was trying to add fragment to activity. i am not sure about other views as i am very new to this.

Comment: i hope you have written like - .add(R.id.mainlayout, new Fragment1()). & had set background is - #ffffff or #FFF. then it should work

Comment: already like that only, but no luck

MainActivity.java : https://paste.fedoraproject.org/375310/65208598/
activity_main.xml : https://paste.fedoraproject.org/375312/14652086/

Fragment1.java : https://paste.fedoraproject.org/375313/52086701/
fragment_fragment1.xml : https://paste.fedoraproject.org/375315/65208704/

fragment.xml : https://paste.fedoraproject.org/375316/14652087/

Comment: use FrameLayout in rootView of activity.

Answer (score 0):

> You can't call Fragments via Intent. Fragment is a part of an FragmentActivity.

All in all Fragment is a content not container, so you need to create a FragmentActivity and add Fragment(Fragment1) in that, and then call on your onClick(),

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SomeFragmentActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

More info : [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Answer (score 0):

use getActivity() from the fragment to access activity functions. If you want to access functions specific to your own activity class. Cast the acticity object you get first before using it see example below

```
MyActivityClass myActivity = (MyActivityClass) getActivity();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one more activity say ExampleFragmentActivity.class, and include fragment tag in ExampleFragmentActivity's layout within Framelayout.

```
public class ExampleFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.example_feagment_activity);
    }
}
```

example_fragment_activity.xml(modified)

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.bentgeorge.fragment.Fragment1">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/titles"
                class="com.bentgeorge.fragment.Fragment1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

In Onclick method of your MainAcitivity.class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainAcitivity.this,ExampleFragmentActivity.class);
```

You can also include fragment dynamically using fragment manager.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1, "fragment");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmenttransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   HomeFragment regcomplainfragment = new HomeFragment();
   fragmenttransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, regcomplainfragment).addToBackStack("HomeFragment");
   fragmenttransaction.commit();
```