# Can't pass data from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem with pass data from activity to fragment, it says null pointer exception, but my data is not null.

This is my activity :

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
    dataj = response.body().string();
    System.out.println(dataj);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("datak", dataj);
    FragmentUtama fu = new FragmentUtama();
    fu.setArguments(bundle);
    Intent load = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    load.putExtra("datajs", dataj);
    startActivity(load);
    finish();
}
```

and this is my fragment :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        String datas = getArguments().getString("datak");
        System.out.println(datas);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_utama, container, false);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: where the fragment transition?

Comment: Where adding Fragment to Activity ?

Comment: and also you need to perfect transition of fragment & activity.

Comment: Sorry, i am paste wrong code

Comment: sorry i paste wrong code. check my question update

Comment: doing wrong first learn how to call a fragment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653037/android-how-to-call-fragment-from-my-main-activity

Answer (score 2):

You don't pass data to fragment via Intents. Arguments are passed by setting them to the fragment instance before calling Fragment transaction commit.

```
SomeFragment f = new SomeFragment ();
// Supply data input as an argument.
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("some_key", value);
f.setArguments(args);
```

then you read it in your fragment.

NOTE: setArguments can only be called before the Fragment is attached to the Activity. So if fragment is already attached, it will not transfer any data to the fragment.

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
int value = args.getInt("some_key", 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry i paste wrong code. check my question update

Comment: @DennyKurniawan, first are you really checking String data via Sysout ? also please share where and when you are adding the fragment to the fragmentmanager ?

Comment: yes, on some devices it can show logs as Log.i, but please use android.util.Log class. Also I have updated the answer, please check the note.

Answer (score 1):

you may try this,

use findFragmentByTag it will help you to find fragment and send data over it.

```
 FragmentUtama fu =(FragmentUtama)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentUtama.class.getSimpleName())
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("datak", dataj);
 fu.setArguments(bundle);
```

or

you can have one setter method in fragment and set data from activity to fragment

from Activity.

```
fu.setData(dataj);
```

In fragment

```
String data;

public void setData(String data)
{
this.data=data;
}
```

use data using getter method of fragment

```
public String getData()
{
return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data to MainActivity using extras of an intent and then using setArguments to pass it to the fragment that belongs to this activity when replacing/adding that fragment to its container.