# Call Fragment from activity

Tags: android

I have a `Navigation drawer` activity and it contains couple of `Fragments`. My problem is I want to call the `Navigation drawer` activity class in `button` click which should have fragment B, by default navigation drawer has fragment A.

I am posting my code here:

```
 back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Navigation.class));
            FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            tx.replace(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentB());
            tx.commit();
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Where content_frame is the area were I want to replace fragment B view..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android How to call Fragment from my Main Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653037/android-how-to-call-fragment-from-my-main-activity)

Comment: I cannot access content_frame which is a view of navigation drawer activity.. so I cannot replace FragmentB to content_frame were there is no view called content_frame in the this (current) activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this approach

in your button click send extra data to check what fragment you need

```
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Navigation.class);
    intent.putExtra("SELECTEDVALUE", 2);//1 for fragament A use 2 for fragment B
    startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Now, in your oncreate() method of Navigation Activity

```
Bundle extras = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState : getIntent().getExtras();
        int selectedValue = extras.getInt("SELECTEDVALUE");

switch (selectedValue) {
                case 1:
                    goToFragment(new A(), false);

                    break;
                case 2:
                    goToFragment(new B(), false);

                    break;
```

finally gotoFragment is...

```
private void goToFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }

        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    }
```

Comment: I will try this

Answer (score 0):

Try below code;

```
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Fragment fragment = new FragmentB();
        FragmentManager fm =getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make an instance of `FragmentB` like this

```
FragmentB fragment - new FragmentB();
```

and then pass it like this .

```
tx.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
tx.commit();
```

now you can access all the variables and methods of fragment from your activity using instance `fragment`. like this `fragment.methodName();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentB(), "fragmentB").addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });
```

hope it'll solve your problem.